# No space between columns on certain pages - with sigplanconf

Tags: spacing, errors, two-column

I'm writing an article using the ACM SIGPLAN's `sigplanconf` document class (with options `letter,10pt,twocolumn,preprint`). I'm using a bunch of packages, and cannot easily reproduce this issue, so excuse the lack of MWE.

My problem is that some of the time, on one of the pages (typically a page with figures, and not the same page every time) - the page is set with no space between the two columns. Here's how a fragment of the page looks (I've blurred it since this needs to go through double-blind peer review):

[image]

There's no overlap of the columns - the right edge of the left one touches the left edge of the right one. In the TeX log, there are several lines saying

> Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active

but somehow I doubt that's where my problem lies. So,

- What 'immediate suspects' should I look out for?
- Have you encountered similar effects in your experience? If so, how did you circumvent them (other than debugging the document class, I mean)?

Again, sorry for the relative vagueness - this is unpublished work. If the log file can help, or the list of loaded packages, or other information - please ask for them in the comments.

Comment: As it stands, the question is clearly unanswerable.

Comment: @egreg: Edited to try to make it more answerable.

Comment: Sorry, too vague.

Comment: It is now 2016 and I am experiencing the exact same problem. Were you ever able to fix or work around it?

Comment: @Calvin: I did work around it somehow, but I really can't remember exactly what I did. It definitely had something to do with playing with float positioning and sizes.